# Output of ros2 node info: what are these publishers/subscribers?

Tags: ros, ros2, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran the following command, trying to find out more about my `/gazebo` node:

```
 user@ubuntu:~$ ros2 node info /gazebo
/gazebo
  Subscribers:
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/ParameterEvent
  Publishers:
    /clock: rosgraph_msgs/Clock
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/ParameterEvent
    /rosout: rcl_interfaces/Log
  Services:
    /gazebo/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/DescribeParameters
    /gazebo/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/GetParameterTypes
    /gazebo/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/GetParameters
    /gazebo/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/ListParameters
    /gazebo/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/SetParameters
    /gazebo/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/SetParametersAtomically
    /pause_physics: std_srvs/Empty
    /reset_simulation: std_srvs/Empty
    /reset_world: std_srvs/Empty
    /unpause_physics: std_srvs/Empty
```

I don't really understand the  output. I understand that `/gazebo` is subscribing to the topic `/parameter_events`, but what is `rcl_interfaces/ParameterEvent`? I thought it was a node that was publishing to `/parameter_events`, but it doesn't show up when I run `ros2 node list` and it also doesn't appear as a node on `rqt_graph`.

I also thought that it might be the location of a file, so I went to search in my ros2 workspace, but I didn't find anything with the same name.

What is it, really?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324495/output-of-ros2-node-info:-what-are-these-publishers/subscribers?/) by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I understand that `/gazebo` is subscribing to the topic `/parameter_events`,

correct.

> but what is `rcl_interfaces/ParameterEvent`?

It is the *type* of the topic. So the message type published to it -- and conversely: the message type a subscriber expects to receive on the topic.

> I thought it was a node that was publishing to `/parameter_events`, but it doesn't show up when I run `ros2 node list` and it also doesn't appear as a node on `rqt_graph`.

it should be clear now why that is the case.

> I also thought that it might be the location of a file, so I went to search in my ros2 workspace, but I didn't find anything with the same name.

Via some intermediate steps, `rcl_interfaces/ParameterEvent` *is* actually a file a package called `rcl_interfaces`. See [index.ros.org/rcl_interfaces](https://index.ros.org/p/rcl_interfaces/github-ros2-rcl_interfaces/#crystal). The exact file is: [ros2/rcl_interfaces/rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent.msg](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/blob/bfa9c43dd7d8cfc5c6fcba8a164d8ef317a386d7/rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent.msg).

See [Introduction to msg and srv interfaces](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Rosidl-Tutorial/) for a (WIP) tutorial on how the message generation infrastructure is used.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on 2019-06-03**:
Thank you very much. I must have not searched thoroughly enough.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-03**:
There should be (or probably is, I just can't find it) some documentation on the output of `ros2 node info`. I'm guessing the assumption is that users have some experience with its ROS 1 equivalent (`rosnode info`).